# Twilio incoming calls when the application is not running ( both Android and iOS )

Tags: android, ios, twilio

The Twilio documentation unfortunately isn't clear enough for me to answer my questions, so here I am.

When my application is running in foreground / background I'm able to receive Twilio incoming connections when a user calls, and I can handle this properly (show a pop-up inside the app, or send local notifications if app is in the background).

Is there any way to implement Twilio incoming calls when the app is not running at all? I'm wondering if is this scenario possible:

1. User A: close application - which has Twilio calls implemented
2. User B: calls User A from an other device through Twilio
3. User A receives local notification for an incoming call ( do I have a twilio connection when the app is terminated to receive a call? )
4. User accepts/declines answering the call right from the notification, without opening the app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe you would need to statically register your broadcast receiver in the manifest or be running a service that runs in the background listening for incoming calls.  Do you have somewhere in your code that you are registering a broadcast receiver? **Disclaimer: I am unfamiliar with Twilio SDK but this is how I would do it in pure Android.**

Comment: **EDIT:** There is a sample here where they statically register the GcM Receiver which then handles the voice call listener.

Comment: This sounds the Android way of doing it. But as far as I understood the Twilio sdk you should have a Device instance which is responsable to talk to the Twillio services. and I don't know how can I keep alive this instance from a Service, and possible handling the Device token expiration cases.

Comment: Look in the mainfest of the sample, they statically declared a service to be used to keep the voice alive:  https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the obvious solution. But let me try to find out the problem. Did you turn the "Voice over IP" ON in background modes?[image: Background Modes in iOS]

Comment: Twilio Client currently does not support VOIP.

Comment: I have just downloaded sample provided by Twilio @https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/client/ios#download-the-ios-app and opened the code with XCode to my surprise Voip is enabled in capabilities. Could you check the Twilio version you are currently using?